# jquery pass ui positions in % rather than screen position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently using this code to post $_GET values to a PHP page:

```
$.get('/includes/sticky_notes/update_position.php',{
    x       : ui.position.left,
    y       : ui.position.top,
    z       : zIndex,
    id  : parseInt(ui.helper.find('span.data').html())
});
```

rather than passing the position of the UI item using PX on the screen can it be done using a percentage?

Reason is, the UI items display on the page using the last set positions and if the screen size is smaller for some users the items display off screen

Comment: You could calculate the percentage by using something like `(ui.position.left/$(window).width()) * 100` and `(ui.position.top/$(window).height()) * 100`. But really the best way would be to update the position on resize or some thing like that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in CSS position via percentage, however you can calculate the percentage by:
    `$(window).width() * .30` this would give you 30% of the screen horizontally.